# Does WinAppDriver provide any Authentication mechanism and/or HTTPS connection?

Tags: security, testing, appium, winappdriver, appium-desktop

I am currently working with Appium and WinAppDriver in order to perform tests on Windows Desktop applications.
Using WinAppDriver is pretty straight forward, it provides a REST API that listens on http://localhost:4327 by default.

Going further in my test cases, I wanted to deploy WinAppDriver in a remote machine, use a secure HTTPS connection and have some sort of Authentication (Basic auth, Token... anything).

The [WinAppDriver GitHub page](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver) doesn't mention any secure connection ways and even the [SECURITY.md](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/blob/master/SECURITY.md) doesn't talk about that.

Anyone already worked with it ? to confirm if WinAppDriver allows HTTPS and/or Authentication ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chromedriver,winappdriver everything follows the same client-server architecture.

The driver exposes available methods throw rest api and we use client libraries to interact with these endpoints.

The usual practice is to have drivers and the target application both in the local system.

If in a remote system then it is assumed that it is within a private isolated network

if you still want https, use selenium4 grid it supports https :

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5073

**see the closing command**

### More simple straightforward approach :

set up a reverse proxy to your local driver server